# Recurrence relation -- simplifying to base case

Tags: recurrence-relations

What would be a closed form relating this recurrence relation $W_n$ to $W_1$?

If
$$W_n = \frac{z_n - 4W_{n-1}}{4n}$$

I keep nested fractions, and I'm not sure how to simplify without algebra being all over the page.

This is basically me forming a relationship with my current semester's WAM (average mark per subject) with the previous semester's, so $z_n$ here is just basically the accumulative marks of the current semester over 4 subjects, so it might have a sequence of $z_k$ in the final result.

I hypothesise that

$$W_1 = \frac{1}{4} \left(\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \: (-1)^k (n-1)! \: z_k \right) + n!\:(-1)^{n+1} \: W_{n}$$
Can someone confirm this?

Comment: what is the meaning of $z_n$?

Comment: $z_n$ is just a constant, that doesn't rely on n, as in it's basically saying it's a constant for the 'nth' period. The intent was to find expression for $W_n$ in terms of $z_n, z_{n-1},.. etc$ as well as $W_1$.

Comment: have you tried Wolfram alpha?

Comment: Not sure what to input, but I input that relation and it doesn't simplify it in W|A.

Comment: @PaulWoch Forget WA to solve the present question (and keep note that the previous commenter's view of mathematics is limited to the blind use of such a CAS).

Answer (score 4):

By multiplying
$$W_n = \frac{z_n - 4W_{n-1}}{4n}$$ by $(-1)^nn!$, one gets
$$
(-1)^nn!\cdot W_n = (-1)^n\frac14(n-1)!\cdot z_n + (-1)^{n-1}(n-1)! \cdot W_{n-1}
$$ or$$
(-1)^nn!\cdot W_n -(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)! \cdot W_{n-1} = (-1)^n\frac14(n-1)!\cdot z_n 
$$ then summing from $n=1$ to $n=N$, on the left hand side terms *telescope*, one has 
$$
(-1)^N N!\cdot W_N -W_{0}=\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\frac14(n-1)!\cdot z_n 
$$ giving

> $$
> W_N=(-1)^N \frac{W_0}{N!}+\frac{(-1)^N}{4N!}\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n(n-1)!\cdot z_n.
> $$

Comment: +1. It's similar to 'integrating factor' in differential equations. Fine.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes it is, thank you.